# map, stability of the fixed point, cobweb

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Map => $x_{n+1}=\sin x_n$

Show the stability of the fixed point $x^*=0$ is not determined by the linearizatin.

Using the cobweb to show $x^*=0$ is stable.

I took derivative of $\sin x_n$ and put $0$. It said equals to $1$.

Am I wrong or how to solve that?

Comment: You're not wrong. But if derivative equals $1$ you can't determine stability by linearization. In case of mappings you determine stability using eigenvalues of Jacobi matrix. If mapping is hyperbolic at fixed point (i.e., non-zero eigenvalues and no eigenvalues $\lambda$ such that $\vert \lambda \vert = 1$), then linearization tells you everything about stability. So you just have to use cobweb to show stability of $x^{*} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

> stability of the fixed point $x^∗=0$ is not determined by the linearization.

This is what you get by observing that the derivative is $1$.

> Using the cobweb to show $x^∗=0$ is stable.

You can draw a "cobweb" diagram, but the reasoning contained in it can also be put in words. Suppose the initial point $x_0$ is in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Within this interval we have $ 0<\sin x < x $ when $x>0$ and $x<\sin x<0$ when  $x<0$. (Consider the positive case; the negative follows by symmetry. Use the fact that $\sin x$ is $\int_0^x \cos t\,dt$.) It follows that  the sequence $x_n$ is monotone and bounded. Hence, it has a limit. The limit must satisfy $x=\sin x$, and the only such point is $0$.